# Как исключить шаблон кастомной таксономии из запроса woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть пользовательская таксономия, к ней, помимо встроенных постов, привязаны еще продукты. И поэтому woocommerce считает, что для архивной страницы этой таксономии нужно подтягивать свой запрос `WC_Query` и свой шаблон woocommerce.php с `woocommerce_contnet();`. Условие на использование шаблона я написал

```
if (is_tax('authors')) {
    include('taxonomy-authors.php');
}
else{   woocommerce_content();  }
```

Это неполный код, но суть такая. Но запрос остается вукоммерсовский, и выводит продукты, как бы я его внутри шаблона не сбрасывал. Можно дописать отдельный `get_posts()` или `WP_Query` на посты, но в основном лупе все равно продукты и из-за этого проблемы с пагинацией. Мне нужна пагинация по постам, а если нет второй страницы с продуктами, то и вторую страницу с постами он не покажет, будет 404.

UPD: нашел в файле class-wc-query.php строчку проверки на принадлежность страницы к продуктам или архивам для `pre_get_posts`

```
// Only apply to product categories, the product post archive, the shop page, product tags, and product attribute taxonomies
    } elseif ( ! $q->is_post_type_archive( 'product' ) && ! $q->is_tax( get_object_taxonomies( 'product' ) ) ) {
```

Если я добавлю в неё условие, все будет работать как мне надо

```
// Only apply to product categories, the product post archive, the shop page, product tags, and product attribute taxonomies
    } elseif ( (! $q->is_post_type_archive( 'product' ) && ! $q->is_tax( get_object_taxonomies( 'product' ) )) || $q->is_tax('authors') ) {
```

Как это сделать хуком или фильтром или экшном, чтоб не менять код плагина?

Answer (score 1):

хук получился такой

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','mandrivets_authors');

function mandrivets_authors($query){
        if( $query->is_tax('authors') && $query->is_main_query() && ! $query->is_admin()) {
            $query->set('wc_query', '');
            $query->set('post_type', 'post');
            $query->set('meta_query', '');
        }
}
```